# Have Superclass Contain List of Subclass?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, class-design

For the GUI of a program, I want it to list several items, all of which are, from a programming side, just subclasses. They can add one of these items to a list. I don't want to hard-code which subclasses there are. What would be the best way to allow the GUI to know about the subclasses, only having the base class to refer to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087401/is-it-possible-to-get-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class

Comment: are you trying to emulate a discriminated union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andrew Timson (+1) makes a superb point about the use of reflection (if possible) and using an interface.

From an Object Oriented Design point of view, Interface's are going to be a much nicer way to go - unless of course there is enough logic in common/inherited to warrant subclassing. This could be argued as part of the "*Dependency Inversion Principle*" at work; "Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.". You're already leaning towards quite a clean solution that adheres to this by avoiding the hard coding though, so nice one!

In addition to that, [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Java) could be the way to go. There's some more information on when reflection should be used over here, on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488531/what-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-java-c-etc)

Other than that, you could use something like an adapted Observer Pattern and have each new instance of a given sub-class *"register"* itself upon initialisation. So there is an object you can query to get all of the objects in question; you could make this a Singleton to ensure it's always accessible throughout the lifecycle of the application - and to make sure there is only ever one object to query.

That's not the neatest solution, but it is another one that could work.

Comment: For singletons created statically, this isn't a problem, but registering on instantiation could mean you'll miss some subclasses (if they haven't been used.)

Answer (score 2):

First off: I think in this case, rather than populating the list with a class/subclasses of it, using some sort of interface may be the more appropriate design.

The best approach is probably going to depend on your language. If it supports reflection (like C# or Java), you may be able to look for other classes that subclass/implement your interface.

If it doesn't - or if you want a simpler solution - you can simply keep the list of available types in some sort of configuration file/table that gets read in at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
import java.util.*;
class Super {
    Super() {
        subclasses.add(getClass());
    }
    static List<Object> subclasses=new LinkedList<Object>();
}
class Sub1 extends Super {
}
class Sub2 extends Super {
}
public class P205597 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub1();
        new Sub2();
        System.out.println(Super.subclasses);
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants a list of classes, not objects. Also, this code will prevent all objects from being garbage collected - massive memory leak.

Comment: He is keeping the Class objects not the instances of the subclasses so there should be no problem with GC imho. However I would change the collection to Set instead of List to avoid duplicities.

Comment: yes, a set would be better since it's a class. i used list because he said list.

Comment: In a more realistic context, where you wouldn't want `main` of a large system to contain a list of subclasses relevant to a particular subsytem, this will not get the full list of classes until an instance of each one has been instantiated (or could be never, if some don't get used in a particular run, depending on user actions, e.g.)